# Sourcetree - upgraded to latest version, git-flow missing

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

Hey I just updated Sourcetree on my mac to the latest version (2.2).
Where did git-flow go?

And how do I re-enable this functionality?

I just lost myself without it!

Comment: In windows is under Repository > Gitflow....but I cannot start a new feature...

Comment: Even though the the functionality can not be completely re-enabled you might want to ask the developers directly to restore the old UI behavior with the toolbar icon still there. You can do that via https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/36182627/sourcetree-please-re-add-an-icon-in-the-toolbar-for-hg-flow-git-flow

Comment: sh.exe C:\Users\donRumatta\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\gitflow_local\gitflow\git-flow feature start OTCTR-67
Completed with errors, see above. - and there is no errors above(= It began to happen after update.

Comment: Git flow is broken with the new version, as per the comment by @donRumatta. I'm downgrading to 1.7 until the next version.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with the command is that it has windows style backslashes.  If you copy out the command and run the following it should work.  Not that this solves the error, but if you ned to get something done right now.  C:/Users/donRumatta/AppData/Local/Atlassian/SourceTree/gitflow_local/gitflow/git‌​-flow feature start OTCTR-67

Comment: Btw, I've found an easier way (I use gitflow a lot).  If you just enclose it in quotes it works too.  So this works, and is a lot less annoying to type when starting with what you see in the sourcetree dialog: "C:\Users\donRumatta\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\gitflow_local\gitflow\git‌​-flow" feature start OTCTR-67

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question but if you are struggling to deal with Atlassian's erratic updates to software, may I suggest GitKraken (http://www.gitkraken.com/), which already seems more stable than SourceTree despite being in beta.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I have the same problem here, you can still use Git-Flow

- From the menu: "Repository-> Git flow /HG flow -> Next action"
- Using the hotkey: "<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

But still not able to get the button back... :/

On the download page the button is also gone:
https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Alternative you can download the previous version here:
http://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/SourceTree_2.1.dmg
https://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/SourceTreeSetup_1.7.0.32509.exe

---

**UPDATE:**

The have a new version of SourceTree Mac v2.2.2(51) / Win: v1.8.2 and when you have this version you can customize you toolbar by clicking on the toolbar with your right mouse button. Then you can enable the git flow button.

*Downloads:*

Mac v2.2.2:
https://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/SourceTree_2.2.2.dmg

Windows v1.8.2:
https://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/SourceTreeSetup_1.8.2.exe

Comment: Is it possible to download old versions for Windows anywhere?

Comment: Added latest windows version also

Comment: The old version is loads better than the new one. I am back to old version. Hope Atlassian retains useful functionality. I am already searching for alternatives.

Comment: They claim to have fixed this in 2.2.1/2.2.2 but I don't see it still, unless they broke it again in 2.2.2.

Comment: Why is it that it's always asking for password on every pull / push? I'm on a mac BTW. It wasn't the case on much older versions.

Comment: Customizing the toolbar works in Mac 2.3.1(69) as well

Answer (score 72):

Here is what you can do if you have SourceTree v2.2.3. (I'm sorry but I don't have enough reputation points to attach the image)

**Edit:** Now I can upload the GIF, thanks!

[Enabling Git-Flow button SourceTree - GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEQhG.gif) 
[image: Enable Git-flow button SourceTree]

Comment: A GIF says more than thousand words... or so.

Comment: Perfect. This also works on version 2.3. Lets boost that reputation of yours!

Comment: While the accepted answer answers the question, it only comes with a work-around. This should definitely be the accepted answer.

Comment: Amazing! Worked with Version 2.3.1 (69) on MacOS Sierra

Comment: Excellent use of gif to illustrate answer clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The corresponding [Windows version is 1.8.1.0](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/update/WindowsReleaseNotes.html).

The hotkey is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

---

**UPDATE:** It appears that Atlassian has pulled release 1.8.1.0. [When you download now, you get version 1.7.0.](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/download/)

Comment: I can't recall the version numbers I've been updating to, but is that a typo? I mean, I see it in "About->Sourcetree" menu but my version's changes and features correspond with this generic release note page: https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/update/ReleaseNotes.html

Comment: They maintain a separate one for Windows: https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/update/WindowsReleaseNotes.html

Answer (score 2):

Jens Schumacher [has just wrote](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/36182627/answers/37030534) that the git-flow button will be back in the next bugfix release. As for now, as others suggested, either roll back to a previous version, or use a hotkey (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for Windows, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for OS X).

Answer (score 2):

Git-Flow button is back as of update 1.8.2.0. So this issue should be resolved: just update SourceTree and it will be back.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11371352)

Comment: well thanks i guess. I would argue that it is helpful information however I will try to follow the guidelines more closely in the future.

Comment: This was useful to me, and does solve the problem...thanks Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

As many people say here, you can use the hotkey

- for OSX <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- for Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

But, also you can **configure the toolbar** to show the gitflow icon again. You just have to do a right click on the toolbar, select "*customize toolbar...*" and drag the icon back to the place it use to be. As simple as that.

I hope it helps.